# sublime text 3 (not responding)

Tags: python, while-loop, sublimetext3

when I use several "While" cycles, in phyton, at the time of executing them the program freezes (does not respond)

I use the windows version, I already tried restoring sublime text 3 to default values.
Below you will have an example in Spanish (it is my native language)

```
respuesta=input("Digite si o no.")

while respuesta=="si":
  a=int(input("digite un numero"))
  b=int(input("digite otro"))
  s=a+b
  print("la suma de ambos es",s)

while respuesta=="no":
  print("adios")
```

when I execute the code in the "Python - Run current file" option, the program does not respond

Comment: You have not used any break condition so it will fall in `infinite` loop.

Comment: Note also that by default Sublime doesn't allow you to interact with a running program. So unless you've set up your own build system that can run a program like this, your problem isn't that you're using too many while loops, it's that you're calling `input` and your program can't proceed past it because you can't give it any  input.